# Creating a network using an adjacency list with python networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to create a Graph with `networkx` but for some reason, I am not getting it.

The 'graph' json file looks like this:

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C', 'E'],
         'B': ['A','D', 'E'],
         'C': ['A', 'F', 'G'],
         'D': ['B'],
         'E': ['A', 'B','D'],
         'F': ['C'],
         'G': []}
```

I am using this code

```
G = nx.read_adjlist("graph.json", create_using=nx.DiGraph())
nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

output:

[image]

Which is not right according to the adjacency list, 'graph'.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you include a link to the documentation you're using?  I have [NX 2.5](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.5/reference/readwrite/adjlist.html), and JSON is not a legal format for adjlist in that verion.

Comment: that's exactly the link I am using @Prune, what do you mean with not a legal format?

Comment: Adjacency format is a text file as shown in the data.  JSON is not mentioned on that page.  There are other routines that convert *between* JSON and adjacency format, but `read_adjlist` deals only with the defined format.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `read_adjlist` command, it expects an input text file.

I presume if you look at your file in raw text it looks something like:

> "A", ["B", "C", "E"], "B": ["A", "D", "E"], "C": ["A", "F", "G"], "D": ["B"], "E": ["A", "B", "D"], "F": ["C"], "G"

It interprets this as a string of comma-separated variables.  So the first thing is the string `"A"` (with the double quotes as part of the string).

This is your first node.  Each string after it is made a neighbor of this first node.  The first four are `["B"`, `"C"`, `"E"]`, and `"B"`.

---

So what do you need to do?  Look at the [networkx commands for json format](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/json_graph.html) and find the appropriate version for how your network is stored (or modify your network storage to have one of these formats).

Comment: thanks for your time. Do you have any recommendation to store the type of data I have already? Thanks!!